# Opening a File in DBFS on Databricks throws an error

Tags: pyspark, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I'm using databricks community edition and when I try to open a file that exists in the DBFS, it throw me an error.
as the image below

[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRylu.png)

First cell, is to show that the file exists.

and Second cell, is trying to open the file

Comment: please don't use images to show errors, or code

Answer (score 0):

"dbfs:/" is missing when you are trying to access the file

Comment: it won't help, because `open` doesn't know anything about DBFS

Comment: even with adding the "dbfs:/" it throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the `open` function that works only with local files, and doesn't know anything about DBFS, or other file systems. To get this working, you need to append the `/dbfs` prefix to file path: `/dbfs/FileStore/....`  (it may not work on community edition with DBR 7.x., so you need to use next recipe)

Or you can just copy this file before reading using the `dbutils.fs.cp` (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html)), like this:

```
dbutils.fs.cp("/FileStore/...", "file:///tmp/local-name")
with open("/tmp/local-name", "r"):
...
```

Comment: you are right! even with adding the "/dbfs/" it throws the same error

Comment: On community edition the /dbfs/ mount don’t work, so you need to use dbutils.fs.cp command to copy file locally, and then read it

Comment: Thanks Alex, much appreciated